# Scene doesn't load in editor but loads perfectly fine in final build

Tags: unity, scene

When my character dies the game is supposed to load a new scene. The code is perfectly fine because it does this when I make a web build for it. But in the editor I get this: [image: UpgradeMenu is the name of the scene that doesn't load]

I have no idea what the issue could be, everywhere I've looked online seems to have the opposite problem (IE: it works fine in the editor but not in the final build). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You *assume* the code is fine for said reason, but there are reasons code could work differently in a build, and not work properly through the editor. I have personally had this happen, before. Could you humor us with the code you use to implement the scene change?